# Display the date dialog of datepicker in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

I want that when the user would click on the the datepicker the small dates window would pop up, my xaml looks like:

```
<DatePicker PreviewMouseDown="DatePicker_PreviewMouseDown"  x:Name="DateTxt"/>
```

In code behinde I need something like:

```
void DatePicker_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{        
    DateTxt.DisplayTheDateDialog;  // <--- need somthig like this
}
```

Comment: Something like what? Is event handler not called or you don't know how to create dialogs?

Comment: I want that the date dialog would pop up automaticly when mouse is down

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13831963/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr Have you tried it? it shows the dialog for less then a second and then disappeared

Comment: Now you have asked a *good* question ;) Try to use another event (it might have something to do with focus, closing popup in one of following up events) or try to queue opening asynchronously via dispatcher (play with priority): `this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => DateTxt.IsDropDownOpened = true);`

Comment: @Sinatr it works now, thank you